# Change values in dataframe Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
  First name    Last name  Height  weight unit
0       Merna         Imel     185      89   kg
1       Taren        Kuehn     189     123  lbs
2     Ginette      Schutte     199      67   kg
3     Natasha       Kibble     180     121  lbs
4    Lucrecia       Berube     191      68   kg
5       Twana    Bonebrake     156     138  lbs
6      Eugena   Felberbaum     165      73   kg
7      Gussie    Eddington     169     114  lbs
8     Siobhan        Krupp     150      56   kg
9      Delcie        Jiron     150     110  lbs
10     Allena     Sandusky     166      87   kg
11      Dylan      Verrill     166     174  lbs
12    Ambrose     Pasillas     186      85   kg
13   Nannette       Lehrer     195     207  lbs
14    Jenifer     Mcgarrah     167      94   kg
15     Tarsha     Jarnigan     162     189  lbs
16      Helen    Macgregor     188     101   kg
17       Kara     Belfiore     179     167  lbs
18     Harvey  Quesinberry     168      74   kg
```

What I want is to change it. So I need for all unit who has "lbs" to change the "weight" to kg by a function "lbs/2.2046". then delete the height column and instead create a new column BMI where the BMI is calculated using the formula "weight/height^2".

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with mask for compare `lbs` and multiple values by constant, for `BMI` divide columns and use `**` for squared:

```
df.loc[df['unit'].eq('lbs'), 'weight'] *= 0.454
df['BMI'] = (df.weight/df.Height)**2
print (df)
   First name    Last name  Height   weight unit       BMI
0       Merna         Imel     185   89.000   kg  0.231439
1       Taren        Kuehn     189   55.842  lbs  0.087297
2     Ginette      Schutte     199   67.000   kg  0.113356
3     Natasha       Kibble     180   54.934  lbs  0.093140
4    Lucrecia       Berube     191   68.000   kg  0.126751
5       Twana    Bonebrake     156   62.652  lbs  0.161295
6      Eugena   Felberbaum     165   73.000   kg  0.195739
7      Gussie    Eddington     169   51.756  lbs  0.093788
8     Siobhan        Krupp     150   56.000   kg  0.139378
9      Delcie        Jiron     150   49.940  lbs  0.110845
10     Allena     Sandusky     166   87.000   kg  0.274677
11      Dylan      Verrill     166   78.996  lbs  0.226461
12    Ambrose     Pasillas     186   85.000   kg  0.208839
13   Nannette       Lehrer     195   93.978  lbs  0.232265
14    Jenifer     Mcgarrah     167   94.000   kg  0.316827
15     Tarsha     Jarnigan     162   85.806  lbs  0.280547
16      Helen    Macgregor     188  101.000   kg  0.288620
17       Kara     Belfiore     179   75.818  lbs  0.179407
18     Harvey  Quesinberry     168   74.000   kg  0.194019
```